# htaccess rewriterule to subdirectory without 301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a question about a `RewriteRule` with `.htaccess` without 301.
Below my directory structure:

```
 -root
 --public
 --app
```

In the root directory I have a directory `public` and `app`.
In the directory `public` I have an `index.php` file.

In the root directory I have a `.htaccess` file and I want all traffic to got to the `index.php` file in the directory `public`.

What I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The rewrite does nothing and I see the index from the directory

Who can help me?

Comment: What URLs are you requesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public/ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

You need to remove the 3rd condition that checks if the requested URL-path starts `/public/`. Presumably, you are making a request for something like `/foo`, so this condition will prevent the rule from doing anything.